# React Router v3 onLeave hook how can I prevent transition to a next route?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to implement preventing transition using ReactRouter v3. I want to use `onLeave` hook but I cannot figure it out yet how to prevent transition from current route to a next one.

We don't plan to upgrade ReactRouter v4 and prefer using `onLeave` not `setRouteLeaveHook`.

Is it possible to implement prevent transition? Thanks

```
 <Route
   path="/test"
   onLeave={ confirmDialog }
   component={ test }
 />

const confirmDialog = () => {
   // prevent transition to a next route 
 }
```